# Funciones de if y else if con sql

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo mi condicional realizado pero solo me funciona el primer condicional, el resto no funcionan. Ya que no realizan lo que se encuentra dentro. Las condiciones if, else if y los operadores de comparación los he probado de todas as formas y sucede lo mismo en uno funciona y en el resto no.

```
try {
    if (Rutinaria.SelectedItem.Value != null) {

        string sql3 = @"select ParadaPlanificada
                        from _EBR_Estado_Lineas where Sistema='{0}';";
        sql3 = string.Format(sql3, this.sLinea.ToString());
        this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.ExecuteSql(sql3);

        DataTable dt3 = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql3).Return;

        this.txtMotivo.Text = Conversor.convertirString(dt3.Rows[0]["ParadaPlanificada"]);
        Log.insertarComentario("", "Parada planificada", txtMotivo.Text);
    }
    if (Rutinaria2.SelectedItem.Value != null) {
        string sql2 = @"select ParadaNoPlanificada
                        from _EBR_Estado_Lineas where Sistema='{0}';";
        sql2 = string.Format(sql2, this.sLinea.ToString());
        this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.ExecuteSql(sql2);
        DataTable dt2 = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql2).Return;
        txtMotivo.Text = Conversor.convertirString(dt2.Rows[0]["ParadaNoPlanificada"]);
    }
    else if (Bausch.SelectedItem.Text != "") {
        string sql2 = @"select Etiquetadora
                        from _EBR_Estado_Lineas where Sistema='{0}';";
        sql2 = string.Format(sql2, this.sLinea.ToString());
        this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.ExecuteSql(sql2);
        DataTable dt2 = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql2).Return;
        txtMotivo.Text = Conversor.convertirString(dt2.Rows[0]["Etiquetadora"]);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.insertarComentario("", "Error motivo de parada", ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: el código parece correcto. Sino la condición no es cierta no se va ejecutar. Has mirado de poner logs y ver los valores de las variables?

Comment: En lugar de Bausch.SelectedItem.Text != "" , use IsEmptyOrWhitespace(Bausch.SelectedItem.Text.)

Comment: Si lo he realizado y sigue igual. También realice pruebas con.           if(!(Rutinaria.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()).Equals(string.Empty)){